# Property change doesn't trigger watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm still somewhat new to Angular and I'm running into a very annoying problem.

I have a variable defined like so:

`$scope.selectedMemberCell = {};`

This gets populated as you click different DOM-elements. You can assign new values. In my case it is an image reference.

```html
<div ng-show="member.selected && overlayActive"
     ng-style="{left: selectedMemberCell.positionInfo.left + 10}">
    <div>
        <div class="mediaButtons-container">
            <a class="b-icon media" ng-click="setEditBlock(selectedMemberCell.imgBlock);">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The block above is the feature I want to use. It's basically an inline image selector based on the position of the element you clicked and will populate the `selectedMemberCell` with additional data.

```js
$scope.$watchCollection("selectedMemberCell.imgBlock.data", function () {
    if ($scope.selectedMemberCell.imgBlock) {
        if ($scope.selectedMemberCell.imgBlock.data[0]) {
            var imgId = $scope.selectedMemberCell.imgBlock.data[0].id;
            api.getRawImage(imgId, $stateParams.ownerid).then(function (result) {
                $scope.selectedMemberCell.image = result.data.url.compressed;
                $scope.selectedMemberCell.imageResourceId = imgId;
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the watch I want to trigger when assigned a new photo. This is where I get stumped. When the ng-show and ng-style is active in the DOM, this watch never activates. However, if I remove them, it triggers.

The following block is the end of the setEditBlock function chain. This triggers in both scenarios.

```js
addToCurrentMediaBlock: function (item, type) {
    if ((this.currentEditBlock.data.indexOf(item) === -1)) {
        this.currentEditBlock.data.unshift(item);
        item.added = true;
    } else {
        this.removeFromCurrentMediaBlock(item, type);
    }
    $rootScope.$broadcast("CONTENT_CHANGE", "");
}
```

If anyone can see obvious pointers here, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Added end of the setEditBlock function chain.

Comment: Any errors in console? Can you show the `setEditBlock` function? `left` should probably be in pixels `px` and not just a number btw.

Comment: setEditBlock is a rabbit hole, but I'll add the code that sets the data. This triggers as well, which leads me to think that the variable is within a child scope of sorts.

Comment: It is not wise to use watchers to trigger asynchronous methods that modify the model as they can be called multiple times per digest cycle. Watchers should only be used to update the DOM or view. Asynchronous methods should only be triggered by events such as inputs or clicks.